# Why would I want less Kinesis when consuming using Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm using AWS Lambda to consume from Kinesis. My Lambda function doesn't have any requirements on max concurrency. Is there any reason for me to not have the maximum possible number of shards for my stream? I can't see that number of shards would affect cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Amazon Kinesis pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/pricing/) shows **price per shard hour**. Data retention (beyond 24 hours) is also charged per shard hour.

So, yes, it will affect your cost.